# How to restore a key binding that does not work correctly?

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, customization, shortcut

I have a very stupid question:

The last weeks I used the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to convert from mesh to curve. If I use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> now, the pop-up menu does not show up, instead the shortcut changes the function of the middle mouse key. Before <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> the middle mouse key zooms in or out – after hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> it does not zoom in/out anymore, but the the whole model moves from left to right or vice versa.

I have completely re-installed blender (`--purge`), and loaded the factory settings. This image shows <kbd>Alt</kbd> shortcuts including <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

[image]

This image shows all zoom view shortcuts:

[image]

My feeling is that somehow <kbd>Alt</kbd> is interpreted as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>, no matter if I use a real keyboard, or a virtual keyboard.

How can I get back the original function of <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>?

Comment: User preferences, search for "convert to" and "zoom view"

Comment: Please see my updated post. And thanks for the suggestion.